# javascript: get a function's variable's value within another function for loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

**fetch variable from another function for loop**

I want to fetch the OTP variable inside for loop from the first function to the second function to verify with other variable values.

```
function validate() {

    var a = document.getElementById("mobile").value;

    if (a == "" || a.length > 10 || a.length < 10) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Enter Valid Mobile Number";
        return false;
    }
    
    if (a.length == 10) {
        var elemB = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
        const url = 'http://samplereques/WRequest?RequestType=UI&phoneNo=' + elemB;
        {
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 1) {
                    otp = data[i].OTP;
                    console.log(otp)
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

function otpvalidate() {
    var ot = document.getElementById("mobile").value;

    if (ot == "" || ot.length > 10 || ot.length < 10) {
        document.getElementById("otpreturn").innerHTML = "Enter Valid OTP Number";
        return false;
    }
    if (ot == otp) {
        alert("sucess");
        console.log("success");
    }
}
```

I want to fetch the OTP variable inside for loop from the first function to the second function to verify with other variable value.

Comment: Where are you calling `otpvalidate` function? Notice also, that some of the used variables are not declared, you're creating a bunch of implicit globals.

Comment: Call `otpvalidate(otp)` from within the `for` loop. Make the function return `true` or `false`, so you can then do `if(otpvalidate(otp)) { do something }`

Comment: At the end of the day, or tomorrow, or when ever OP is responsive again, this will eventually be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron